# NSIS - check if process exists (nsProcess not working)

Tags: process, nsis

For my NSIS uninstaller, I want to check if a process is running. FindProcDLL is not working under Windows 7 x64, so I tried nsProcess.

I've downloaded the version 1.6 from the website: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsProcess_plugin

If I start the nsProcessTest.nsi in the Example folder, I get the following errors:

```
Section: "Find process" ->(FindProcess)
!insertmacro: nsProcess::FindProcess
Invalid command: nsProcess::_FindProcess
Error in macro nsProcess::FindProcess on macroline 1
Error in script "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\nsProcess_1_6\Example\nsProcessTest.nsi" on line 14 -- aborting creation process
```

This is line 14 of the example script:

```
${nsProcess::FindProcess} "Calc.exe" $R0
```

Do somebody know what is wrong? How can I check if a process is running with NSIS?

Comment: For the compilation error did you put nsProcess.nsh in include directory of NSIS installed folder? Same for nsProcess.dll file? I'm using nsProcess FindProcess and KIllProcess under Win7 x64 without any issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

NSIS does not find the plug-in, so make sure you copied its files to the correct folder.

**NSIS 2.x:**

```
NSIS/
├── Include/
│   └── nsProcess.nsh
└── Plugins/
    └── nsProcess.dll
```

**NSIS 3.x:**

```
NSIS/
├── Include/
│   └── nsProcess.nsh
└── Plugins/
    ├── x86-ansi/
    │   └── nsProcess.dll
    └── x86-unicode/
        └── nsProcess.dll
```

The file inside `Plugins\x86-unicode` is `nsProcessW.dll` renamed to `nsProcess.dll` (blame the author for making it overly complicated!)

More generally, refer to [How can I install a plugin?](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_can_I_install_a_plugin%3F) on the NSIS Wiki.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Include`,  not `Includes`?

Comment: @ivokosir Thanks, fixed my answer

Comment: thank you for the `nsProcessW.dll renamed to nsProcess.dll`